# Unhandled event loop exception - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I can not create hibernate.cfg.xml

I try update Eclipse but it not work

> org.eclipse.ui
>   Unhandled event loop exception
>   Exception Stack Trace:

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:184)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_4.internal.util.MetadataHelper.buildFromMetadataSources(MetadataHelper.java:49)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_4.internal.util.MetadataHelper.getMetadata(MetadataHelper.java:21)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_4.internal.ConfigurationFacadeImpl.getMetadata(ConfigurationFacadeImpl.java:174)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_4.internal.util.ConfigurationMetadataDescriptor.createMetadata(ConfigurationMetadataDescriptor.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.buildMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.getMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.setupContext(AbstractExporter.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractExporterFacade.start(AbstractExporterFacade.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.openContentStream(NewConfigurationWizard.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.access$2(NewConfigurationWizard.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard$1.getInitialContents(NewConfigurationWizard.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.createNewFile(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.performFinish(NewConfigurationWizard.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.handleConfigurationFileCreate(ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.handleConfigurationFileSetup(ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.access$2(ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationMainTab$4.widgetSelected(ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog(DebugUITools.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog(DebugUITools.java:656)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.AddConfigurationAction.doAddConfiguration(AddConfigurationAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.AddConfigurationAction.run(AddConfigurationAction.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 89 more
```

Comment: Maybe this? `Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

Comment: Can you post `hibernate.cfg.xml` ?